# Loss of AsyncLocal<> context with kestrel during json serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.text.json, kestrel-http-server

I'm using nuget **Microsoft.ServiceFabric.AspNetCore.Kestrel 6.1.1799** and **System.Text.Json** for serialization.
I'm also targetting .NET 6.0.

I've instanciated a middleware in which I create an `AsyncLocal<>` state to time-monitor my request and seek for potential bottle-neck issues.

Everything works fine inside controllers, `ActionFilter` attributes, authorization policy (JWT token events) and other parts of the code.
But this is not the case during serialization/deserialization.

While implementing `IJsonOnDeserialized`, `IJsonOnDeserializing`, `IJsonOnSerialized`, `IJsonOnSerializing` interfaces on my business objects, the `AsyncLocal<>` state instanciated in middleware is often not found.

Let me be clear, it works when I test my API using single requests with POSTMAN for instance.
It does not work anymore when I launch a load test, ie with a lot of simultaneous requests hitting the server.

Here is, I hope, relevant code that I use - I tried to remove anything useless.
Here for base business object

```
public abstract class CMonitor : IJsonOnDeserialized, IJsonOnDeserializing, IJsonOnSerialized, IJsonOnSerializing
{
    #region Properties

    [JsonIgnore]
    private Watch Serialization { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private Watch Deserialization { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Serialization

    public virtual void OnDeserialized()
    {
        this.Deserialization?.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnDeserializing()
    {
        this.Deserialization = new Watch("{0} >>", this.GetType().Name);
    }

    public void OnSerialized()
    {
        this.Serialization?.Dispose();
    }

    public void OnSerializing()
    {
        this.Serialization = new Watch("<< {0}", this.GetType().Name);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is for my Watch code. With serialization/deserialization I hit the `Debug.WriteLine` error inside the constructor.

```
public class Watch : Elapsed, IDisposable
{
    #region Properties

    private static AsyncLocal<WatchContainer?> _CurrentWatcher;
    public static WatchContainer? CurrentWatcher
    {
        get
        {
            return _CurrentWatcher.Value;
        }
        set
        {
            _CurrentWatcher.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public Watch(string pName, params object[] pArgs)
    {
        if (pArgs != null && pArgs.Length > 0)
        {
            pName = string.Format(pName, pArgs);
        }

        this.Name = pName;
        this.StartTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        if (Watch.CurrentWatcher == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("WATCH CONTAINER NULL for WATCH={0}", this.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Watch.CurrentWatcher?.Add(this);
        }
    }

    static Watch()
    {
        _CurrentWatcher = new AsyncLocal<WatchContainer?>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.EndTimestamp == 0)
        {
            this.EndTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

An now, this is my middleware

```
public class LogMiddleware
{
    #region Properties

    private RequestDelegate Next { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public LogMiddleware(RequestDelegate pRequestDelegate)
    {
        this.Next = pRequestDelegate;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        Watch.CurrentWatcher = new WatchContainer();

        using (new Watch("OuterTreatment"))
        {
            await this.Next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions : Is this a known issue ? Am I doing something wrong ? Is there another way to monitor serialization/deserialization that would not break the AsyncLocal<> context ?

Many thanks for your answers.

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the container

```
public class WatchContainer : Elapsed
{
    #region Properties

    public List<Watch> Watches { get; private set; }

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public WatchContainer()
    {
        this.StartTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        this.Watches = new List<Watch>();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public void Add(Watch pWatch)
    {
        lock (this.Watches)
        {
            this.Watches.Add(pWatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the base Elapsed class

```
public abstract class Elapsed
{
    #region Properties

    public long StartTimestamp { get; protected set; }

    public long EndTimestamp { get; protected set; }

    public double Delay
    {
        get
        {
            return Math.Round(1000.0 * (this.EndTimestamp - this.StartTimestamp) / Stopwatch.Frequency, 4);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Here is my configured middleware pipeline for kestrel

```
               builder
                .UseMiddleware<LogMiddleware>()
                .UseRouting()
                .UseAuthentication()
                .UseAuthorization()
                .Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    using (new Watch("Treatment"))
                    {
                        await next();
                    }
                })
                .UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                   endpoints
                        .MapControllers()
                        .RequireAuthorization();
                });
```

EDIT

Here is a sample of what is traced in log file.
One can see that serialization/deserialization happen AFTER hitting the middleware "LogMiddleware".

[image: ASCII art representation of the watch container]

And a part of the missing `Trace` method inside WatchContainer, called at the end of `LogMiddleware.Invoke()`

```
    public void Trace(string pIdentifier, bool pStats)
    {
        Watch.CurrentWatcher = null;
        this.EndTimestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();

        // algorithm to trace in log file.
        // then send the container to a Q that writes into a csv file
    }
```

Comment: I see a couple of problems: the type in the async local is not immutable, and the business interfaces you're using are lifecycle hooks instead of middleware style. If you post complete code you can get some better suggestions.

Comment: @Stephen I know I'm diverting the usual use of AsyncLocal<> :( Which missing part of the code is relevant in your opinion ? WatchContainer ? Json configuration for kestrel ?

Comment: You don't have any control over how the json serialization lifecycle events are called, correct? I'm wondering why you would need an AsyncLocal at all.

Comment: @Stephen No I have no control over serialization and deserialization, kestrel does that by itself. I use an AsyncLocal<> cause the WatchContainer is used to display graphically the request time consumption once the request is over. Watch class is called everywhere in the code in a multi-threading environment. One request can trigger parallel tasks.

Comment: I think I get what you're doing now. It just took a while, since `Watch` type has the shared `CurrentWatcher` which holds the `WatchContainer` which holds the `Watch` instances. I'd recommend moving `CurrentWatcher` out of `Watch` entirely just for the sake of your sanity. Other than that, the only thing I can see wrong is that `LogMiddleware` should be _clearing_ `CurrentWatcher` when it's done (in a `finally` or via a `using` `IDisposable` wrapper). I'm wondering if the JSON serialization is being done _after_ the middleware...

Comment: @Stephen, In fact, CurrentWatcher is cleared after having called Trace() that displays a nice ASCII ART graphic in log files + send all data to a flat .csv file for excel further investigations. I didn't add the method here for clarification ^^'

Comment: @Stephen I think there is a bug inside kestrel with System.Text.Json that does not provide correctly the TPL context. But I can't find a way around it.